# How to displaying and hiding again the div after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to display a hidden div after clicking a button by adding an extra class `addClass("open");` and then using css to display them when it is active `open` class.

```js
$(".btt").click(function(event){
   ($(event.currentTarget).parent().parent()).addClass("open");
});
```

```css
.surveySummaryList>li .surveySummaryMenu {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position:absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 250px;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.surveySummaryList>li.open >.surveySummaryMenu {
  display: inherit;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav surveySummaryList">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:" data-bind="click: $root.surveyClicked">
      <span>Name</span>
      <button class=" btt pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></button>
    </a>
    <div class="surveySummaryMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar">
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:" data-bind="click: $root.surveyClicked">
             <span> Sub Name </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And only when I click to the button, the div `class= surveySummaryMenu` should display, even if I click  this `<a>` tag, it should not display. It seems working but then after clicking to the button, the div .surveySummaryMenu will stay remain forever, how can I hide it again after clicking somewhere else, not the button?

Comment: why would u put a button inside an anchor ?, u dont need any of the data-bind attrs, instead of using parent(), u can just give an id or a class to the div u want to target and then select it, lastly anything inside the div u r selecting will inherit its parent event.

Comment: becasue I want to display the hide div only when I click to the button. Even when I click to the a tag, it should not display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use the `event` object for `event.currentTarget`, you need to pass it to the callback function.

like this:

```
$(".btt").click(function(event) {
```

**The working code:**

```js
$(".btt").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().addClass("open");
});

$('.nav a').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('.open').removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.surveySummaryList>li .surveySummaryMenu {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position:absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 250px;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.surveySummaryList>li.open >.surveySummaryMenu {
  display: inherit;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav surveySummaryList">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:" data-bind="click: $root.surveyClicked">
      <span>Name</span>
      <button class=" btt pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></button>
    </a>
    <div class="surveySummaryMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar">
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:" data-bind="click: $root.surveyClicked">
            <span> Sub Name </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Note** By the way, you can use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.currentTarget)` - I was changed the code so you can see it in the snippet.

Comment: thanks Mosh, it works, one more question I would like to ask is: now when we click to the button, the new div is displayed, it's clear. But then it will stay remains there forever, I guess. How can I hide them again after I click somewhere else, for example

Comment: I was updated the answer. Let me know if you OK with it.

Comment: it works anyway, but can I use this code instead Mosh? `!($(".btt")).click(function(){
  $('.open').removeClass('open');
 });`

Comment: I tried but it not working but I think this could be one solution, that means whenever I click to somewhere else NOT the button .btt, the class open should be removed, maybe the syntax wrong, I dont know

Comment: I don't understand `it not working` what **exactly** not working? Can you create a [bin](http://jsbin.com/) with this issue?